# Oracle Date Selection

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Below given is my Loan_Details table.

```
INST_MONTH  START_AMOUNT
---------       ------------
17-JUN-16           10500
11-FEB-16           4500
11-MAR-16            4125
11-APR-16           3750
11-MAY-16           3375
11-JUN-16           3000
11-JUL-16           2625
11-AUG-16           2250
11-SEP-16           1875
11-OCT-16           1500
11-NOV-16           1125
11-DEC-16           750
11-JAN-17           375
```

My query is

```
select INST_MONTH 
from loan_details 
where to_char(INST_MONTH,'MM- YYYY') > to_char(TO_DATE('9/11/2016','MM/DD/yyyy'),'MM-YYYY')
```

When I need to select all the months greater than 11-OCT-2016 it always returns

```
INST_MONTH
---------
17-OCT-15
17-NOV-15
17-DEC-15
11-OCT-16
11-NOV-16
11-DEC-16
```

Why am I missing `11-JAN-17`?

(For the moment consider the month and year only)

Comment: `to_char(TO_DATE('9/11/2016','MM/DD/yyyy'),'MM-YYYY')` it completely useless. It's a complicated way of writing `'11-2016'`. What data type is `inst_month`? If that is a `date`, then calling `to_date()` on it to convert a `date` value to a `date` value doesn't make any sense. Simply use `where inst_month > date '2016-09-11'`. Btw. `9/11/2016` is not `11-OCT-2016` it's September, the 9th (2016-11-09)

Comment: God Save Me 
Please give me a way to compare  a date regardless the date.I need to compare month and year only

Answer (score 1):

You are wrongly comparing a `Date` column with character match by using `to_char`.

Your query should be:

```
select INST_MONTH from loan_details
 where INST_MONTH > TO_DATE('9/11/2016','MM/DD/yyyy')
```

And for only month and year comparison, you can use this:

```
select INST_MONTH from loan_details
 where TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(INST_MONTH, 'MM-YYYY'), 'MM-YYYY') > TO_DATE('09-2016','MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: @code_Finder: Of course, 9/11/2016 is 11-SEP-2015 and not 11-OCT-2015 as you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks mate.. Give me a way to compare month and year only

Comment: You can try this: `select INST_MONTH from loan_details where TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(INST_MONTH,'MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY') > TO_DATE('09-2016','MM-YYYY')`